# Google Sheet ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK returning error

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

I am updating my array formula but the updated formula is erring out.

**Original formula:**
[=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TODAY()>O2:O,"Past due",IF(TODAY()<O2:O-7,"Upcoming due date","Due this week")))](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N8ynLVrlSDPFbu7pwhkTrDfrp8Q7rbKaBkw0EoITKSU/edit?usp=sharing)

**Updated formula:**
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(O2:O),"Not Started",IF(I2:I="Delivered","Delivered",IF(((TODAY()>O2:O)*(I2:I<>Delivered,"Past due",IF(TODAY()<O2:O-7,"Upcoming due date","Due this week")))))))

What I want this formula to do is:

1. If Column O is blank, display text "Not Started"
2. If Column O is not blank and today's date is greater than Column O **AND** Column I doesn't equal "Delivered", display text "Past Due"
3. If Column I is "Delivered", display text "Delivered"
4. IF(TODAY()<O2:O-7,"Upcoming due date","Due this week"

I am sharing my workbook, URL hyperlink available.  The formula will live in Column AE "Due Week".  Assistance needed and appreciated.

[image: Google sheet]

Comment: why does the spreadsheet look like someone graffiti'd on it

Comment: I don't know lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(O2:O),"Not Started",IF(I2:I = "Delivered","Delivered",IF(TODAY()>O2:O,"Past due",IF(TODAY()<O2:O-7,"Upcoming due date","Due this week")))))
```

You had the right idea. Once you get that deep in, you know I2:I is not delivered, so that triple parentheses and multiplication with today should not be needed.Also, I think you needed quotes around "Delivered" where you said <>"Delivered". The * should work, but simplifying it with an AND helped me fix your formula to

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(O2:O),"Not Started",IF(I2:I="Delivered","Delivered",IF(AND(TODAY()>O2:O,I2:I<>"Delivered"),"Past
 due",IF(TODAY()<O2:O-7,"Upcoming due date","Due this week")))))
```

Still no need, because we know it's not "Delivered" when we are in that deep.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was so close.  Thanks!